# How to filter string in multiple conditions python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data=['5Star','FiveStar','five star','fiv estar']
data = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["columnName"])
```

When I try to filter with one condition it works fine.

```
data[data['columnName'].str.contains("5")]
```

Output:

```
    columnName
0   5Star
```

But It gives an error when doing with multiple conditions.

How to filter it for conditions **five** and **5**?

Expected Output:

```
    columnName
0   5Star
2   five star
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `str.contains` with a string with values separated by `'|'`:

```
print(data[data['columnName'].str.contains("5|five")])
```

Output:

```
    columnName
0   5Star
2   five star
```

Comment: it works I had given data[data['columnName'].str.contains("5"|"five")] that's why I ended up with error

Comment: @panda Happy to help, :-), 

Comment: how to store the same result in another dataframe

Comment: @panda Do: `newdf=data[data['columnName'].str.contains("5|five")]`, sorry for my lateness.

Comment: @panda Good that i could help more, :-)

Comment: how can I make it filter all at once? i mean an AND contition

Comment: @user3325706 `data[data['columnName'].str.contains("(?=.*5)(?=.*five)")]` should do

Comment: Taking this solution Thanks