# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() for a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

def scrap_hrefs(url,baseUrl):
    resp = requests.get(url, headers= header)
    respData = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')     
    allHrefs = respData.select('[href]')
    
    return allHrefs, baseUrl
   
def get_hrefs(allHrefs, baseUrl):
    for i in range(0,len(allHrefs)):
        if allHrefs[i]['href'].startswith('/'):
            allHrefs[i]= baseUrl + allHrefs[i]['href']
        else:
            allHrefs[i]= allHrefs[i]['href']
            
    return allHrefs

def store_hrefs(allHrefs):
    links = {'links' : allHrefs}
    df = pd.DataFrame(links).drop_duplicates()
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        if df['links'].str.contains('https')==False:
            df.drop()        
    df.to_csv("example_home_page_links.csv", index=False)
    
    return df
    
def run_scraper(url,baseUrl) :
    store_hrefs(get_hrefs(*scrap_hrefs(url, baseUrl)))
     
    
run_scraper('https://www.example.com/','https://www.example.com')
```

this code is giving the following error :

**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

I want to remove all the rows in which 'https' is not there(i.e. remove all the invalid links/content).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change remove `False` output in loop:

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if df['links'].str.contains('https')==False:
        df.drop()
```

to filter only rows with match condition in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['links'].str.contains('https')]
```

Comment: thankyou. it worked! but I'd like to understand the solution you gave. 
what does df[df['links'].str.contains('https')] mean? 
and also, why was the for loop and if condition giving an error?

Comment: @SoumyaPandey - Sure. `df['links'].str.contains('https')` is boolean mask - it means Series filled by `True/False` values. If pass to `df[mask]` it is called `boolean indexing` - it means only rows with `True` in mask are returned, `False` rows are removed. If check linked `boolean indexing` there is explain more.

Comment: @SoumyaPandey - Your original solution return from  `df['links'].str.contains('https')` mask for all values of column in loop, so for each index same output. Here looping is not necessary, because pandas boolena indexing is fast way for filtering by some mask.

Comment: Yes, thanks. your solution worked! :)
I do have another question. What if instead of looking for just one string i.e 'https', I want to look for more strings? Then the .str.contains() fails.

Comment: Then use `.str.contains('https|http')` for test `https` or `http` - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812967/how-to-filter-string-in-multiple-conditions-python-pandas)

Comment: aah! that's great. awesome it worked.
But I'll have to add so many words here. 
like, I wanted to store links which has the following keywords. So I modified the code as :
df = df[df['links'].str.contains('financial|investors|investor|report|filings|news|media')]
But in the future I want to be able to add more words to it. and I want to store this set of words somewhere else. How would I do that ?